For certain field extensions $[L_1:F]<\infty$, $[L_2:F]<\infty$, $L_1 \simeq L_2$, when $[L_1:F]=[L_2:F]$?
Let $\mathbb{C} \subset F \subseteq L_1 \subseteq \bar{F}$, $\mathbb{C} \subset F \subseteq L_2 \subseteq \bar{F}$ be field extensions, with $[L_1:F]=n_1<\infty$ and $[L_2:F]=n_2<\infty$, $\bar{F}$ is an algebraic closure of $F$.
Moreover, since we work over $\mathbb{C}$ and the extensions are finite, the primitive element theorem says that there exist $w_i \in L_i$ such that $L_i=F(w_i)$, $1 \leq i \leq 2$.
Question 1: If we further assume that $L_1 \simeq L_2$ as $\mathbb{C}$-algebras (not necessarily as $F$-algebras), does this imply that $n_1=n_2$?
If not, is there an additional condition that would imply $n_1=n_2$?
Question 2 (later edit): If $L_1 \simeq L_2$ as $F$-algebras, then $n_1=n_2$, right?
Question 3 (later edit): If we further assume that $L_i$ is root closed in $\bar{F}$, does this imply that $n_1=n_2$?
Where $L_i$ is root closed in $\bar{F}$ if $w^n \in L_i$ implies that already $w \in L_i$, $w \in \bar{F}$. This would be a plausible answer to "is there an additional condition that would imply $n_1=n_2$?" in Question 1.
Several remarks:

We know that the minimal polynomial of $w_i$ over $F$ has degree $n_i$, $1 \leq i \leq 2$.
This question and its answers seems relevant.
I do not mind to further assume that $n_1$ and $n_2$ are prime numbers; in this case, this question implies that $L_1=L_2$ (and we are done, because then obviously $n_1=n_2$) or $L_1 \cap L_2 =F$.
I am asking the current question in order to understand the answer here; I do not understand why $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):R]=[L:R]$.

Thank you very much!

Take $F=\mathbb{C}(t)$, $L_i=\mathbb{C}(t^{1/n_i})$.

Thank you! Your counterexample is a nice variaton on the second followimg answer, changing $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^6)$ to $\mathbb{C}(t)$ etc. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821849/isomorphic-fields-of-finite-degree-have-same-dimension-over-base-field Please, could you help me with remark 4?

Perhaps in the MO answer, because the Galois extension fixes $F=R=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$, we have $[L:R]=[\mathbb{C}(x,y):R]$.
